# Facebook Marketing API - How to optain Ads Management STANDARD ACCESS?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-permissions

I have filled the form here. https://www.facebook.com/business/standardadsapi

Also my facebook business manager fulfilling all the facebook terms like having 25+ Ad accounts.

But didn't get any response from facebook. Is there any other way I can try to obtain permission from facebook.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not a facebook support forum

Comment: As it says there, _“We will get back to you once we have fully evaluated your application.”_

Comment: @Vikash Pathak Have you gain the permission from Facebook? I had been applied since more than 2 weeks ago but still didn't receive any reply.

Comment: Yeah @Ping yesterday, you should have to wait...it''ll take longer then expected. about 15-25.

Comment: Wow I thought they said it will just taking 14 days, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten Standard Access for multiple apps, usually it takes a few days after you have filled in the application form. So just wait. Check your App's Settings page once in a while, if you get no notification whatsoever after a week or so, shoot FB a message.

Comment: I had been applied since more than 2 weeks ago yet still did not receive any reply, may I know where to shoot them a message?

Comment: Did you check if your application was approved? As I recall I did not get any direct notification. Regarding asking a question, they do not have any direct contacts, but there should be a support contact somewhere around the Facebook Developers site. I am not around my computer for a few days so won’t be able to look up unfortunately.